# I am looking for a font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I've got to make a website for a customer and I can't figure out which font was he using. I've tried a whole lot of them. Here is a picture of a text using this font:

[image: HAND font image]

It looks like Arial in bold but the "N" and the "A" are "pointy" and I can't find any font looking like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transat](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/typetanic-fonts/transat-text) and [Steagal](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/insigne/steagal) are both pretty close, but picking the exact weight is tricky. Steagal in particular has the distinctive flat top "D" that I think Century Gothic etc lack. Plus Century Gothic has a flat bottom "N" when rendered in bold.

[image]

Comment: I think it might be Steagal Bold, the H seems to have the right width and the flat D is fitting perfectly. I'll let you know but I think you nailed it ! Thanks ! :D

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of fonts that look like that including Futura, Metro and Century Gothic. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

None of them look quite as bold as the font in your image so it could be something different or one of the above with a stroke applied to fatten it up a bit.

Screen grabs are from myfonts.com